# what is the difference between semaphore and critical region?

Tags: semaphore

the only thing i understood is

- semaphore is a primitive way
- critical region has a GUARD variable  (semaphore also does but the name is not GUARD!)

??

so whats the difference?

Comment: will study more then slct answr, thnku for patience

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, a critical region is a place where, if two separate threads of execution were to be present, a race condition or some other undesirable effect would occur. Semaphores are one way of preventing two threads from being in the critical region at the same point in time.

Answer (score 2):

The GUARD would only allow 1 thread to enter the critical region at a time, whereas the semaphore can allow n threads (you specify n) to concurrently enter the critical region.

Answer (score 1):

When a process executes code that manipulates shared data (or resource), we say that the process is in it’s critical section (CS) (for that shared data) 
and semaphore is Nonnegative integer variable used as a flag and 
Signals if and when resource is free

Answer (score 0):

There are two interpretations of "critical region":

1. A region of code that will produce undefined results if executed simultaneously by two threads.
2. A region of code that is isolated from *all executors except for the current thread*.  An example of this would be an interrupt handler.  These regions are more commonly called "critical sections".  On Intel CPUs you can begin/end a critical section with the CLI/STI instructions.

Comment: Note that on a virtual-memory OS, CLI/STI may not be sufficient to guard a critical section.  If code tries to access a memory page that is not immediately available, that will trigger an interrupt regardless of whether asynchronous interrupts are enabled.  The "expectation" is that that interrupt will fetch the necessary page from disk and return to the executing code, but nothing in the hardware would prevent the OS from executing any other threads while waiting for the required page to be read.